# Can not install ProjectRTC with node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm creating webRTC with library on here: https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC
But with ProjectRTC-master, I've run command to install but not success:
npm install:

```
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1",
"npm":"3.3.3"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","
npm":"3.3.3"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","
npm":"3.3.3"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1
.1","npm":"3.3.3"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","
npm":"3.3.3"})

> ws@0.4.31 install D:\AndroidWorkspaceE\ProjectRTC-master\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


D:\AndroidWorkspaceE\ProjectRTC-master\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config
_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-g
yp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebu
ild )

> ws@0.4.31 install D:\AndroidWorkspaceE\ProjectRTC-master\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


D:\AndroidWorkspaceE\ProjectRTC-master\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config
_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-g
yp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebu
ild )
ProjectRTC@0.4.0 D:\AndroidWorkspaceE\ProjectRTC-master
├─┬ body-parser@1.14.0
│ ├── bytes@2.1.0
...
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON ProjectRTC@0.4.0 No license field.
```

and npm start:

```
> ProjectRTC@0.4.0 start D:\AndroidWorkspaceE\ProjectRTC-master
> forever start app.js

warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up f
or at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

I'm not sure about what problem I got. I'm also not be familiar with node.js. I just using it for create client-side android application (for testing). Anyone can help me???

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of node.js? Check plz. Command "node -v".

> vladislav@vladislav-X555LA ~/WebstormProjects/ProjectRTC $ `node -v`
>   v0.10.25
>
> vladislav@vladislav-X555LA ~/WebstormProjects/ProjectRTC $`npm start`
>
> ProjectRTC@0.4.0 start /home/vladislav/WebstormProjects/ProjectRTC
>   forever start app.js
>
> warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
>   warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not >stay up for at least 1000ms
>   info:    Forever processing file: app.js
>   vladislav@vladislav-X555LA ~/WebstormProjects/ProjectRTC $ `forever list`
>
> info:    Forever processes running
>   data:        uid  command         script  forever pid  id logfile                           >uptime
>   data:    [0] v8AH /usr/bin/nodejs app.js  6671    6673    >/home/vladislav/.forever/v8AH.log 0:0:0:2.994 
>   vladislav@vladislav-X555LA ~/WebstormProjects/ProjectRTC $ `tail -f /home/vladislav/.forever/v8AH.log`
>
> `Express server listening on port 3000`

In version v0.10.25 all ok.If you have problem in another version just downgrade it.

Comment: my node version is 4.x, but when I download v0.10.25 and run it, it still can not working right:npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.2
5","npm":"1.3.24"})...

Comment: Just install nvm, link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm. This package for managing different versions of node. Use v0.8.x. And u dont have problem with webRTC lib.

Comment: But wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.2 5","npm":"1.3.24"}).
It does not prevent the server starts.

Comment: but i think if when i download ver 0.8.x or 0.10.x also still error, NVM or NVMW is the same essence

Answer (score 0):

Just write after "npm start"

```
forever list
```

and see "nano path/to/log/file"
if you see :

`Express server listening on port 3000`

Without error. That all ok.